# fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: scikit-learn, svc

I try to fit `SVC` in `skikit-learn`, but got `TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in the line SVC.fit(X=Xtrain, y=ytrain)`

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()


from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_circles
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


X, y = make_circles(100, factor=.2, noise=.2)
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=42)

svc = SVC(kernel = "poly")
SVC.fit(X=Xtrain, y=ytrain)
predictions = SVC.predict(ytest)
```

Comment: dont you must indique the test size?? `Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=42)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the model here `svc = SVC(kernel = "poly")`, but you're calling the fit with a non-instantiable model.

You must change the object to:

```
svc_model = SVC(kernel = "poly")
svc_model.fit(X=Xtrain, y=ytrain)
predictions = svc_model.predict(Xtest)
```

I suggest you to Indique the test size, normally the best practice is with 30% for test and 70% for training. So you can indicate.

```
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
```

Comment: @KaterinaMelnikova Also note that you will need to supply the `Xtest` to the `predict` method and not `ytest`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Well, the idea is to get knowledge about how good is the model predicting new data. I'm gonna update the response for you